# How to retrieve full client info using 'javascript'

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

Using Navigator object you are able to get visitors browser info and history. Also using 'google.ClientLocation' you can get the location info.

My question is what more data you can retrieve from visitor using javascript/jquery? 
Does google have any object similar to ClientLocation for ClientInfo for instance?

**Note: The scenario states that only javascript is available.**

Comment: What information are you interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thing to remember: Any data you receive from Javascript is sent from the user's (client's) computer.  The client can therefore spoof the data that you receive.  An easy way to do this, for example, is the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) addon in Firefox.

You're better off (but still not 100% sure) getting information from a server-side script.  For starters, [here's a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931485/how-to-track-users-location-region-in-php/3931574#3931574) to find location, using PHP.