# ip based content based on country

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IP to Country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/ip-to-country)
>   [IP To Country in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295970/ip-to-country-in-php)

I have a website where I am storing *user's IP address* when they visit. I want to server them IP based first page content. I think I can store IP ranges in database and when the users come from those ranges I can serve them specific content.

But the question is just after typing website address the website will load and it will show the default content. Please tell how can I achieve this?
So that I can serve country based content to my users.

Suppose if IP address is;

```
IP Address: 109.97.86.2
```

It should detect that it is *Romania* and it should present pages which is designed for *Romania*.

Comment: Obligatory NB: IP adresses and countries are loosely correlated (massive exceptions exist both ways, even before the client starts using proxies and VPNs).

Comment: I hate websites that make assumptions about me just because of my IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP to Country databases are often out of date - a better approach might be to put the flags of the various countries your customers come from at the top of  the site and let people self-select.  This way if Mom in the UK is talking with her son in Japan, they can both see the same site if they wish.

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the various geoip databases; i think the one from [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/country) is the most popular one.

Then simply perform the ip=>country lookup when a new user goes to your site and display the content for his country.

Comment: obvious duplicate. dont answer those. closevote please